# Running into error: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I created a defined function to add one month if the 'SR_NUMBER' is the same as the row above. I get the error message: 'float' object is not subscriptable. Here is the code I ran and the desired output:

dtypes:
SR_Number: object

year_month_end: datetime64[ns]

Code attempt:

```
def SRfunction(row):
    if row['SR_NUMBER'] == row['SR_NUMBER'].shift(1):
        return row['year_month_end'] + MonthEnd(1)
    else:
        return row['year_month_end']

df['SR_NUMBER'] = df['SR_NUMBER'].apply(SRfunction)
```

Error message: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Original df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SR_NUMBER':      ['2-15642332176', '3-22596843941', '3-22596843941', '3-22596843941', '3-22596843941'],
                   'year_month_end': ['2020-02-28', '2020-04-30', '2020-04-30', '2020-04-30', '2020-04-30']})
```

Desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SR_NUMBER':       ['2-15642332176', '3-22596843941', '3-22596843941', '3-22596843941', '3-22596843941'],
                   'year_month_end':  ['2020-02-28', '2020-04-30', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31']})
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is different from [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).

In this case `row` is not a row at all, but a single `float` value from the `SR_NUMBER` column.

If your applied function needs data that spans multiple columns, you need to use the `DataFrame` form of `apply`, but you are currently using the `Series` form.

Comment: THank you! Could you maybe elaborate further on how the full code would look if you were to fix it?